# how i can store date and time with default value in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

i m using below code to create a table in that table i want store date and time in two seprated columns and set date and time default also using below query but getting this error

```
create table location_aj
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  vehicle_id varchar(10), 
  latitude float(12,2),
  longitude float(12,2), 
  price float(15,2), 
  fdate DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, 
  ftime TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
);
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE, ftime TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME)' at line 1

please help

Comment: I think CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_TIME not available in mysql in default option. only current_timestamp avaibale

Answer (score 2):

There is no static default value for `date` and `time` seperately in MySQL.

You could use a trigger to set the date and time on insertion. Or use a single `datetime` column with default value `current_timestamp`:

```
create table location_aj
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  vehicle_id varchar(10), 
  latitude float(12,2),
  longitude float(12,2), 
  price float(15,2), 
  fdatetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Default values need to be constant and not a function/expression, hence it does not allow you to use the current time and current date for setting the default values for TIME & DATE respectively.

From [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

**Data Type Default Values**

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that DATE/TIME.
Try the below,

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)

Answer (score 0):

** **we can not use any function with default in MySql.** **
You can store current time and date using in insert query at time time of date insertion.
or u can give some fix date and time, i thing which u don't want......
like
create table location_aj
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  vehicle_id varchar(10),
  latitude float(12,2),
  longitude float(12,2),
  price float(15,2),
  fdate DATETIME DEFAULT '2008/08/26'
);
we can take date from now() using : select DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d/%m/%Y');
and current time using : select CURTIME();